# Changing fill color of SVG when loaded from outside source into img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have quite a few SVG icons saved in different *.svg files. If I insert them into the page directly I can freely control their colors with the fill css option.
My trouble comes that I need to change the color of the svg and then display it in an img tag, because an important for the project library can only work with that. Is there a solution to my predicament?

```
<img src='img/graphic.svg' />
```

I need to be able to change the color of the svg and receive similar or the same end result. Is this even possible?

**EDIT**

Is it possible to include javascript in the svg file that will read parameters and change color accordingly? For example:

```
<img src='img/graphic.svg?fill=fff' />
```

I am not sure how can this be achieved.

Comment: it is possible but tricky depending on how complex your svg is, can you create a snippet for the same?

Comment: Paulie, this is not a duplicate. I need the end result to be an image tag, not svg tag. As I said the library is really picky and works only with img tag. The duplicate you showed converts the image tag into svg tag.

Comment: Saurabh, some are simple, but there are some using rect, circle, path and polygon all-together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your svg doc as a dataURL :

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22first%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20250%20250%22%20height%3D%22250%22%20width%3D%22250%22%3E%20%20%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2260%22%20cy%3D%2260%22%20r%3D%2250%22%20fill%3D%22pink%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"/>
```

So, either you download the file through xhr, append it to an svg element and then convert it to this dataURL,

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var svgDoc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.response, "image/svg+xml");
svgDoc.querySelector('#yourElement').setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', yourColor);
var dataURL = encodeURIComponent(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgDoc));
img.src = dataURL;
```

or you load it through an `<object>` or an `<iframe>` element and then convert its `contentDocument` :

```
var obj = document.createElement('object');
obj.src = "path/to/your/file.svg";
obj.onload = function(){
  var svgDoc = obj.contentDocument;
  svgDoc.querySelector('#yourElement').setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', yourColor);
  var dataURL = encodeURIComponent(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgDoc));
  img.src = dataURL;
}
```

Of course, these solutions are limited by the cross-origin policies.

Comment: Also note that if `<image>` elements are present in the document, they would have to be converted to dataURL as well in order to be displayed in the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Is this the only way to access elements like lines and circles inside a loaded SVG image? (without using inline SVG?)